# How to use Custom Action Controller in .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Could you tell me how to use my own action controller?
I have created class `CustomActionSelector : IActionController` and implemented functions: `SelectBestCandidate` and `SelectCandidates`.
I also have registered my service in Startup.cs in ConfigureServices function like:

```
services.AddSingleton<IActionSelector, CustomActionSelector>();
```

This is my `SelectBestCandidate` function:

```
public ActionDescriptor SelectBestCandidate(RouteContext context, IReadOnlyList<ActionDescriptor> candidates)
{
    var controllerActionDescriptor = new ControllerActionDescriptor();
    controllerActionDescriptor.ControllerName = typeof(SecondController).Name;
    controllerActionDescriptor.MethodInfo = typeof(SecondController).GetTypeInfo().GetMethod("Index");
    controllerActionDescriptor.ActionName = controllerActionDescriptor.MethodInfo.Name;
    return controllerActionDescriptor;
}
```

I think it should always redirect to Index() action of SecondController but it doesn't work.
What else should I do?

This is my ConfigureService function

```
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            
            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
            services.AddControllers().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();

            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

            services.AddSingleton<IActionSelector, CustomActionSelector>();
            
            services.AddMvc( options => {
                options.Conventions.Add(new ControllerNameAttributeConvention());

            });
          
        }
```

Comment: It's typo in my question, sorry

Comment: That's ok. If you put a breakpoint, is the method ever called?

Comment: Unfortunately not, and I don't know why.

Comment: Your injection might be replaced with the default one. Can you [edit] your question to include your entire ConfigureServices (where you configured all services if renamed)?

Comment: OK, I add ConfigureServices to my question

Comment: You can try `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute`.

Comment: Im my Action Selector class?

Comment: I test your code,and also cannot call the method,here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762910/mvc3-use-of-actionmethodselectorattribute-causes-httppostattribute-to-be-ignore) about ActionMethodSelectorAttribute